# Change NSWindow size with Storyboard

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, storyboard

I'm new using Storyboards for OS X and I can't find the way to change the Window size from my NSViewController

I tried

```
var window = self.view.window!
...
window.setFrame(frame, display: true, animate: animation)
```

but it doesn't work:
[image]

Comment: `but it doesn't work` Please always be more precise. What happens, something not expected, or nothing happens? Error message, no error? Etc. Thanks. :)

Comment: @EricD. The question was updated with the error. :) Why did i get that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work. Are you sure you don't have same frame what your window's frame currently is? If so, this should work:

```
let window = self.view.window!
window.setFrame(NSRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 400, height: 400), display: true, animate: true)
```

Comment: The frame is ok, the problem is with the **window**. The question was updated with the error.

Comment: In IB, did you set your NSViewController subclass matching your class what you are using?

If you make new project that code will work.

Comment: Thanks, it works with a new project and also my code works with a new project `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`